# Auto update (download and install latest app version) programmatically

Tags: android, mobile

Can anyone enlighten me on how to programmatically auto update (download and install latest version) an app with/out opening the said app? then display it in a notification. Do I need a 3rd party platform or etc., Can anyone provide me with an easy-to-understand sample code as a reference.

Comment: I don't think that's possible on Android. I've never seen it, anyway. All you can do is test for the latest version when your app is opened and then ask the user to update it via the App Store.

Answer (score 0):

You could use 3rd party library like [AppUpdater](https://github.com/javiersantos/AppUpdater) and implement it in a [background service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services)

Possible implementation:

In **activity**:

```
onCreate() {   
...
// schedule updater service
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        SchedulerUtils.scheduleNextUpdaterService(applicationContext)
    } else {
        SchedulerUtils.scheduleRepeatingUpdaterService(applicationContext)
    }
}
```

whole SchedulerUtils: https://gist.github.com/neone35/e463c418bbea0ecc9ac699a7e7f02a1b

Example **service**: https://gist.github.com/neone35/f8ce2a8d62b81e8abcefd53f06417263

And replace service logoutCourier() with similar to this:

```
private fun checkForUpdates() {
        mAppUpdater = AppUpdater(this)
                .setDisplay(Display.DIALOG)
                .setDuration(Duration.INDEFINITE)
                .setUpdateFrom(UpdateFrom.JSON)
                .setUpdateJSON(Constants.AUTO_UPDATE_URL)
                .setTitleOnUpdateAvailable(getString(R.string.update_found))
                .setContentOnUpdateAvailable(getString(R.string.update_app_descr))
                .setButtonUpdate(getString(R.string.download))
                //.setButtonDismiss(getString(R.string.postpone))
                .setButtonDismiss("")
                .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_logo)
                .setButtonDoNotShowAgain("")
                .setCancelable(false)
        //.showAppUpdated(true) // to test out - show even when no update
        mAppUpdater.start()
    }
```

Comment: Hello, the nuget package AppUpdater is already deprecated. Do you have any alternative for this library? By the way I am using xamarin to build the App.