# Update a mobile application automatically when the app is launched

Tags: android, ios, mobile, google-play

On a cross platform mobile application in React native, I want to publish a new light version of my application (for example add some assets) without the need to go through the play store and download an update. After my research there are plugins like in-app update for android (https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-updates) which propose the update to the user when the application is launched, but it's not totally what I'm looking for. I would like an update in the background when the application is launched without having a popup from the Playstore. I have in mind Clash Royale which has an updating screen of a few seconds at game launch.

From a global point of view, what is the strategy to adopt to publish an update. Big updates need to go through the store and minor ones can be done in the background?

Comment: You could use 3rd party library like https://github.com/javiersantos/AppUpdater and implement it in a background service. See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75018957/1818596

Answer (score 1):

You can use Microsft App Center/Code Push Service, with this service you can update your app inside the application without sending GooglePlayConsole or AppStoreConnect.

https://appcenter.ms/

https://microsoft.github.io/code-push/

https://github.com/microsoft/react-native-code-push

Also you with appCenter you can

- Build and deploy in the cloud.
- Track your analytics
- Do your tests on real devices
- Monitor the app
- Target your deployments